# iPod touch 4G internal microphone?

Tags: ipod-touch, microphone

Based on the [specs page](http://www.apple.com/ipodtouch/specs.html), Apple seems to indicate that the 4th gen iPod touch has an internal microphone. Is this true, or are they merely indicating its compatibility with the headphones-with-remote-and-mic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has a microphone. It is the little hole beside the back camera (no idea why they put it there).

Comment: That could be why it's there, but in my experience it captures audio from the front very well too. It even works well when the iPod is sitting on a table, so the microphone is pretty much touching.